# If $f'(c)$ exists then $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=f(c)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> If $f'(c)$ exists then $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=f(c)$

My attempt is below. Did I do wrong? Since I don't really understand it. I thought $f'(x) = f'(c)$ so $f'(x)-f'(c)=0$. Am I on the right track? Many thanks!

\begin{align}
f(x)-f(c)&=\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\cdot(x-c) \\
\lim_{x\to c}[f(x)-f(c)]&=\lim_{x\to c}\left[\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\cdot(x-c)\right] \\
\lim_{x\to c}[f(x)-f(c)]&=0 \\
\lim_{x\to c} f(x)&=f(c)
\end{align}

Comment: What are you supposed to prove? That $\lim\limits_{x\to c} f(x) = f(c)$?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Because I think f'(x)-f'(c) = 0 if c is existed on the f(x)

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Gotcha! Just re-edited it.

Comment: To Eff: yes! I don't really get it

Comment: To AlexR: thank you so much! Just rewrote it:)

Comment: Thank for someone re-edited my post! Many thanks! Hmm...sorry for making troubles on writing math...

Comment: Nitpicking, but there should be a comma before 'then' (in the picture above).

Comment: Right! Thank user314!

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to prove is equivalent to proving $f(x)-f(c)\to0$ as $x\to c$. Note that $f(x)-f(c)=(x-c)\cdot\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$. What happens as $x\to c$?

Comment: Nope. I am trying to prove lim x->c f(x) = f(c).

Comment: That's the same thing.

Comment: Oh! May you explain more because I thought they are different....sorry

Comment: $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=f(c)\iff\lim_{x\to c}(f(x)-f(c))=0.$ What happens when you apply $\lim_{x\to c}$ to my equation?

Comment: I see. Got it! Right. They will have same result

Answer (score 1):

Since $f'(c)$ exists, we can say that $f$ is differentiable at $c$.

So far you have shown 
\begin{align}
f(x)-f(c)&=\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\cdot(x-c) \\
\lim_{x\to c}[f(x)-f(c)]&=\lim_{x\to c}\left[\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\cdot(x-c)\right] \\
&=0\\
\end{align}

which tells us that the difference $f(x)-f(c)$ tends to $0$ as $x$ tends to $c$. But you still have to show that  $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=f(c).$

Using  $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}[f(x)-f(c)]=0$, which you have just shown, we proceed with the remainder of proof:

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to c}f(x)&=\lim_{x \to c}[f(c)+(f(x)-f(c))]\\
&=\lim_{x \to c}f(c)+\lim_{x \to c}(f(x)-f(c))\\
&=f(c)+0\\
&=f(c).
\end{align}